# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' when working with the PINS on the Map

Tags: ios, mapkit, xcode4.2

When i run my app, it crashes and i got this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AnnotationsDisplay coordinate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x795bda0'
```

`AnnotationsDisplay` it's a class to manage displaying the PINS on the Map.

**EDIT:**
This is my AnnotationsDisplay class code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface AnnotationsDisplay : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {
    NSString *title;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;
@end
```

**.m:**

```
#import "AnnotationsDisplay.h"

@implementation AnnotationsDisplay
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
    title = ttl;
    coordinate = c2d;
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@protocol MKAnnotation <NSObject>

// Center latitude and longitude of the annotion view.
// The implementation of this property must be KVO compliant.
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@optional

// Title and subtitle for use by selection UI.
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *subtitle;

// Called as a result of dragging an annotation view.
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 4_0);

@end
```

Properties are already declared in MKAnnotation protocol. Just add @synthesize for each property.

Comment: I mist the protocol, so he need to fully implement the protocol, fixe that init method and that should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's impossible to tell where exactly your error is, but it looks like you're using your AnnotationDisplay instance in wrong place, and it's attempted to be sent with `coordinate` message, that is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Does your AnnotationsDisplay conforms to MKAnnotation protocol?

Comment: You forgot to add @synthesize for coordinate, title and subtitle.

Comment: I use Xcode 4.2, i think it is not supported since i work with ARC

Comment: it is supported, but the ivar are not define as property, so synthesize won't work alone

Answer (score 0):

An init method should almost always call `super`.
Here is an exemple for a UITableViewController

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

}
return self;
}
```

since you are subclassing NSObject, there is a lot in the initialization of NSObject that will put your object in a valid state.

And in your code it should be like this

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
self = [super init];  // init from NSObject
if (self) {
  title = ttl;
  coordinate = c2d;
}
return self;
}
```